# How do I get docker-compose up to work when I get "[emerg] 1#1: > BIO_new_file failed SSL error"

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, docker, curl, nginx

I have set up a Docker registry successfully before.  I am trying to do it again. I am on step 6 of these [directions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-docker-registry-on-ubuntu-14-04).  The first part works.  I am using Ubuntu 16.04.  I do not think that is the problem because I have gotten it to work on 16.04.

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
nginx:
  image: "nginx:1.9"
  ports:
    - 5043:443
  links:
    - registry:registry
  volumes:
    - ./nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
registry:
  image: registry:2
  ports:
    - 127.0.0.1:5000:5000
  environment:
    REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY: /data
  volumes:
    - ./data:/data
```

I run this command: `sudo docker-compose up`

This it he error that I get:

> nginx_1     | 2017/11/17 05:37:24 [emerg] 1#1:
>   BIO_new_file("/etc/nginx/conf.d/domain.crt") failed (SSL:
>   error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or
>   directory:fopen('/etc/nginx/conf.d/domain.crt','r') error:2006D080:BIO
>   routines:BIO_new_file:no such file) nginx_1     | nginx: [emerg]
>   BIO_new_file("/etc/nginx/conf.d/domain.crt") failed (SSL:
>   error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or
>   directory:fopen('/etc/nginx/conf.d/domain.crt','r') error:2006D080:BIO
>   routines:BIO_new_file:no such file) dockerregistry_nginx_1 exited with
>   code 1

I have put the domain.crt in /etc/nginx/conf.d/.

I have made sure that root was the owner and the permissions were 600 for domain.crt.

What am I doing wrong?  I expect docker-compose up to start the nginx service for port 5043 to work.

This command works from a duplicate terminal:  curl http://localhost:5000/v2/
This command does not work from a duplicate terminal: curl http://localhost:5043/v2/

The "emerg" error that I pasted above with nginx concerns me.  How can I get docker-compose to work without a serious error so I can do basic curls to the localhost over port 5043?  I want to progress.

Comment: Jermoe, you have used the `blockquote` instead of the `code sample` and the formatting of your question doesn't help others quickly reproduce your problem.

Comment: Is it ok now? There have been a few changes.